# How to prove or disprove that a union of two anti-reflexive relations is also anti-reflexive

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $R$ and $S$ be binary relations on a nonempty set $A$. Then $S \cup R$ is also a binary relation on $A$.
Suppose $S$ and $R$ are anti-reflexive relations on $A$.
How can we prove or disprove that $S \cup R$ is also anti-reflexive?

Comment: If $D\subset A^2$ is the diagonal ($D=\{(a,a):\ a\in A$) and $R\cap D=\emptyset$ and $S\cap D=\emptyset$, then $(R\cup S)\cap D=(R\cap D)\cup (S\cap D)=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

A relation $T$ on $X$ is anti-reflexive iff for all $x \in X$, $(x,x)$ is not in $T$.

Now, given that $S$ and $R$ are both antireflexive, and if $x \in X$ is arbitrary, $(x,x) \notin S$ and also $(x,x) \notin R$ and so $(x,x) \notin S \cup R$.
Hence $S \cup R$ is anti-reflexive.